# Validation failed: InvalidRoleName

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have some problem with the code. I'm not able to create a role. The code seems fine to me, but I'm not able to find the error. With WriteLine I'm getting the following message:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager: Warning: Role 38676182-f211-47d7-b69b-f190e4338123 validation failed: InvalidRoleName.
```

Why InvalidRoleName is invalid? It's just a string. Any help is appreciated.

c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Sarpinos.Pages.Admin
{
    public class CreateRoleModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        public CreateRoleModel(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public List<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newRole = new IdentityRole();
                newRole.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(newRole);
                Console.WriteLine($"{newRole.Id} {newRole.Name}");
            }

            return RedirectToPage("Dashboard");
        }
    }
}
```

cshtml:

```
@page
@model Sarpinos.Pages.Admin.CreateRoleModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}


<div class="container">
    <form asp-page="CreateRole" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Roles">Role name:</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Roles" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter role name" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Roles" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you pass ```newRole.Name``` as from what I see from here, you are declaring a new ```new IdentityRole()``` without RoleName. That's why it doesn't pass the validation as the name should not be null or empty.
Try adding ```newRole.Name = "ANY_ROLE_NAME";``` after ```newRole.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();```. You may also need to pass role name from the form POST to ```"ANY_ROLE_NAME"```.

Comment: the newRole.Name it is supposed to be filled from the form on post. I fixed the issue, On cshtml input I added 'name="Name"' and 
c# 
var theName = Request.Form["Name"];
newRole.Name = theName;
altought I'm not sure why the binding is not working as it is.

Comment: I suspect the binding does not work as you expected because you are binding ```List<IdentityRole>``` instead of ```IdentityRole``` as ```<input type="text"/>``` should only be a single value instead of multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     [BindProperty]
>     public List<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
>     public void OnGet()
>     {
>     }
>
>     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
>     {
>         if (ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             var newRole = new IdentityRole();
>             newRole.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
>             await _roleManager.CreateAsync(newRole);
>             Console.WriteLine($"{newRole.Id} {newRole.Name}");
>         }
>
>         return RedirectToPage("Dashboard");
>     }
> ```

According to your description, it seems that you want to create a new Role, but by using the above code, it looks that you are using a `List<IdentityRole>` to display the roles and in the post method, you didn't set the role name for the newRole. So, it might cause the issue.

To Create new Role, in the CreateRoleModel, you could create a new class which contains the Role related properties. For example:

```
public class CreateRoleModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public CreateRoleModel(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager) { _roleManager = roleManager; }
    public class NewRole
    {
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public NewRole Input { get; set; } 

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Input = new NewRole(); //
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newRole = new IdentityRole();
            newRole.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            newRole.Name = Input.RoleName;
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(newRole);
            Console.WriteLine($"{newRole.Id} {newRole.Name}");
        }

        return RedirectToPage("Home/Index");
    }
}
```

Then, in the CreateRole.cshtml page, based on the NewRole class to insert a new role (you could change the namespace to yours).

```
@page

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model IdentitySample.Pages.CreateRoleModel

<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Input.RoleName">Role name:</label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Input.RoleName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter role name" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Input.RoleName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    </form>

</div>
```